# do I need to resubscribe to market data after reset?

Tags: quickfixj

I am using quickfixj to subscribe to market data. Noticed that after midnight reset, I will not receiving incremental anymore. How do I know if I am still subscribed to the the session?
Do I need to resubscribe each time when I logged on again?

Answer (score 1):

It of course depends on the target system that you're connecting to. Some systems will maintain subscriptions across sessions, but the vast majority will not.

You probably need to resubscribe.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but I figured out that I need to resubscribe. Since the initiator is not down but the acceptor is down at that period of time. When Accepter started, the initiator was still trying to connect, once connected, the subscription is not triggered.
So the solution is to add subscription in the onLogon callback, so each time it got logged on, it will try to subscribe again, so the stream is not lost.